# Flutter - SimpleDialog in FloatingActionButton

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a `SimpleDialog` after a tap on the `FloatingActionButton`, however when pressing that button nothing happens.

What was I doing wrong?

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(new ControlleApp());
}

class ControlleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      tooltip: 'Add',
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFF44336),
      onPressed: (){
        new SimpleDialog(
          title: new Text('Test'),
          children: <Widget>[
            new RadioListTile(
              title: new Text('Testing'), value: null, groupValue: null, onChanged: (value) {},
            )
          ],
        );
      }     
    ),    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to wrap this on a show action dialog.

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
   return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text("My Super title"),
      content: new Text("Hello World"),
   );
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. It's also likely that you will eventually want to get the result of the dialog, in which case you can `await` the result of `showDialog` and put the value you want to return in a call to `Navigator.pop()` in the dialog action.

Comment: After many tries I finally found the issue to my problem: If your app declares a list of `localizationDelegates` but you forget to include `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate` and/or `GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate` then the dialog won't show at all

Comment: This is now outdated

Answer (score 94):

I noticed the accepted answer is using `child` for `showDialog` which is actually deprecated, so I would recommend avoiding it. You should be using `builder` instead, I've provided an example:

```
onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Dialog Title'),
            content: Text('This is my content'),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gil! Btw you spelt my surname wrong O'Sullivan not Sullivan :)

Answer (score 12):

There is a specific scenario which should be taken care while showing the dialog from `floatingActionButton`

if you write your code like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (ctxt) => new AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Text Dialog"),
                  )
              );
            }),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

It will not show Alert Dialog but throws an exception "No MaterialLocalizations found."

This happens when the `MaterialApp` is not the root where the dialog is called. In this case the root widget is the Application. However, if we change the code as

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppImpl()
    );
  }
}

class MyAppImpl extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (ctxt) => new AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Text Dialog"),
                )
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

The `MaterialApp` becomes the root and everything works fine.  In this case flutter automatically creates Material Localiation which otherwise needs to be manually created.

I didn't find any documentation for the same in the official doc.

Hope it helps